# Fullcalendar function to create event data from url query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, fullcalendar

I'm trying to take some parameters passed in the url as a query string and create the necessary event arrays to load data into fullcalendar.  I have looked at the event function for taking data from a JSON feed and tried amending this for my needs unsuccessfully.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to take an array of query string values (this part I am fine with) and then get fullcalendar to load these as events.  Thanks in advance.

Sean

**Updated with example code of the arrays i'm creating from query string.  Example test url like so: /test.html?Event=Test1,Test2,Test3&Date=2013-04-01,2013-04-02,2013-04-03**

```
        var qsParm = new Array();

    qsParm['Event'] = null;
    qsParm['Date'] = null;
    qs();


    function qs() {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var parms = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) {
            var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0) {
                var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
                var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
                qsParm[key] = val;
            }
        }

        var title = qsParm['Event'].split(',');
        var start = qsParm['Date'].split(',');
```

Comment: Could you add some example code? For example whta does the array of strings look like?

Comment: Thanks i've added the code i'm using to create the arrays from the query string.

Comment: In theory the code should work, make sure your qsParm['Event'] is set to something using console.log(qsParm); Preferable in firefox with firebug or Chrome as they give detail about logged objects.

Answer (score 0):

your string to date:

```
var i = 0;
var start ="27,8,72".split(",");
for(i=0;i<start.length;i++){
  start[i]=parseInt(start[i],10);
  if(isNaN(start[i])){
    throw(new Error("Invalid date:"+start.join(",")));
  }
}
var date=new Date(start[2],start[1]-1,start[0]);
console.log(date);
```

The new Date(year,month,day) is used. Note that month is month-1 since date constructor uses zero based months so 0 is January.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The code I entered above is working ok for me, it's the next part using the title and start arrays with an event function which will work with the fullcalendar script that is causing me problems.  The example given on the website is a function that will take an XML feed, i've tried various functions based on this code but I can't get any to work.  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/